# TypeError: uuid_1.v5 is not a function

Tags: typescript, uuid

Attempting to generate a UUID with the package [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) using these steps:

### Installation

```
npm i -S uuid @types/uuid
```

### Code

```
    import { v5 } from 'uuid';
    const MY_NAMESPACE = '1b671a64-40d5-491e-99b0-da01ff1f3341';
    console.log(v5('Hello, World!', MY_NAMESPACE));
```

When I run that I get:

```
    TypeError: uuid_1.v5 is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ole/slice/test.ts:3:13)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to submit a PR to fix the type definitions or shall I?

Comment: Looks like you really know what you are doing, so if you could that would be awesome!  Thank you very much!

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/28439

Comment: Converted cuid to Typescript in case anyone needs it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/cuid

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DefinitelyTyped is wrong: the `uuid` module does not export `v5`.  Your import should be:

```
import v5 = require('uuid/v5');
```

Or if you have `esModuleInterop` enabled, you can use:

```
import v5 from 'uuid/v5';
```

Answer (score 8):

I was also getting the similar problem.

Try the following and it will work.

```
//I use v4 so , but try .v5 if you want to
const uuid = require('uuid').v4

//now can call uuid
uuid()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//import uuid

import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid'

//call uuid

id:uuid
```

Answer (score 4):

In TypeScript Backend

Try the following and it should work.

```
    import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
```

then call like:

```
id: uuid()
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

with require module

> `const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid'); uuidv4();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're from the future (present) and seeing this page, please reinstall uuid. You've probably got some version `< 3.3.3` installed. As of today, the current version is 8.x, which does export v5.